# php if, else if, and if on blocks of code that also contain php statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to use `<?php if (statement): ?>`, `<?php else if (statement): ?>`, and `<?php else: ?>` lines to make my code more readable.  I'm not quite sure if this is the correct syntax.  I also wonder if I can use php code within these if blocks. This is what I am working with:

```
<?php $blogexcerpt = $Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 250); ?>
<!-- if the blogexcerpt contains less than 5 non-white spaces assume there is media and use the "View Media" tag -->
<?php if ( strlen(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $blogexcerpt)) < 5 ): ?>
<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">View Media…</a></h5>
<!-- else if the blog post is less than excerpt length post entire -->
<?php else if ( strlen($Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 255)) < 250 ): ?>
<?php echo $blogexcerpt; ?>
<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">View post</a></h5>
<!-- else show excerpt -->
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $blogexcerpt; ?><span style="display: inline;">…</span>
<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">Read more…</a></h5>
<?php endif>
```

Comment: Oh. Wow. Um.... You should also move your CSS to an external stylesheet.

Comment: "to make my code more readable" - I don't think it worked!

Comment: Dude, have you thought about looking at the documentation... http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: @trickyzter Yes I have looked at the php documentation and it says nothing about using php if statements for blocks of code '<?php if (statement): ?>'

Comment: By all means make your code more readable. Before using endif instead of brackets, please do add newlines and indenting.

Comment: And for those you on the readability train, I never said the code was readable.  I just said to make it more readable I wanted to use php if blocks. I am just starting making it more readable and yes @Paul CSS separation is next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case I would go for all PHP to make it readable:

```
<?php
$blogexcerpt = $Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 250);

if ( strlen(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $blogexcerpt)) < 5 ) {
    echo '<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="' . $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; . '" class="blog_post_link">View Media…</a></h5>';
} else if ( strlen($Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 255)) < 250 ) {
    echo $blogexcerpt;
    echo '<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="' . $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; . '" class="blog_post_link">View post</a></h5>';
} else {
    echo $blogexcerpt;
    echo '<span style="display: inline;">…</span>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="' . $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; . '" class="blog_post_link">Read more…</a></h5>';
}
```

Although this might just be personal preference I think this is way more readable then keep mixing opening and closing PHP mode by all those `<?php ?>` all over the place.

Some IMHO benefits:

- opening and closing curly braces (although opinions differ for templating stuff, you see what you like best)
- proper indentation
- no opening and closing `<?php ?>` tags all over the place

**PS**

Are you sure that the posts are html entity encoded? And are you sure you really want to decode them? Most of the times you can just get away with `htmlspecialchars()`. And decoding before displaying is often a bad idea and may introduce XSS vulnerabilities. Not sure in you specific case though. Just a reminder to watch what you are doing :-) E.g. are you sure you want to decode it and not encode it to prevent XSS?

**PPS**

One final thing. You should really drop that inline CSS as [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168744/php-if-else-if-and-if-on-blocks-of-code-that-also-contain-php-statements/12168787#comment16287335_12168744) stated in his comment while we are busy making it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Michael,

The short answer is yes.

You do need to endif with a semicolon: `<? endif; ?>`

Comment: He also has to remove the gap between 'else if'.

Comment: @Byron Thanks for the short answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes indentation will help make things readable (wrapped in a document to show how PHP/HTML indenting can coexist):

```php
<?php
$blogexcerpt = $Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 250);
?>
<html>
    <body>
<?php if ( strlen(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $blogexcerpt)) < 5 ): ?>
        <h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">View Media…</a></h5>
<?php elseif ( strlen($Blog->create_excerpt(html_entity_decode($post->content), 0, 255)) < 250 ): ?>
        <?php echo $blogexcerpt; ?>
        <h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">View post</a></h5>
<?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $blogexcerpt; ?><span style="display: inline;">…</span>
        <h5 style="margin:0px;"><a href="<?php echo $Blog->get_blog_url('post').$post->slug; ?>" class="blog_post_link">Read more…</a></h5>
<?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```